# jQuery change top css randomly not working

Tags: jquery

I wanted to have the `top` position of the box be random every time it moves from left to right and right to left but it seems not to be working. But if I just put in `'0'` it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlin/z5guptvv/7/ (top values are constant - works)
https://jsfiddle.net/iamdevlin/z5guptvv/8/ (top values are random - not working)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve but if you want to keep your top moving from `0` remove the 
`$(box).css("top","0"))` and use random variables such as `$(box).css("top", genRanTop());`

Comment: I've updated my question and I called the function inside the `css()` but the randomization doesn't work.